# how wordpress smtp works? my emailing is not working

Tags: smtp

All of my wordpress emailing is not working.
I have created a test file for smtp emailing. it works OK. I put on /test.php and works great!
So I think that hosting or server don't cause this problem.

But on wordpress, all of emails are not working! I use budddypress and contact form 7.

removed all of plugins(23 plugins) except contact form 7. but contact form 7 is not working.

1. Do I need to setup wordpress emailing to active?
2. Could it be a Database problem? 
   We moved database to this server(single site) from another server (multi-site). the tables were on 2nd blog for
   multi-site (you know the table names are like wp_post_2....etc). and changed to the 1st blog (single-site). when we were moving, we changed table names from wp_post_2 to wp_post.
   it works fine except emailing. I don't know if you understand what I am talking about changing table names. we moved 2nd blog on multi-site to 1st blog on single-site.

if this problem is with moving database (changing table names), how I check? Do I need to check any tables?
which file I should check or test for emailing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress sends mail using the PHP `mail()` function. The easiest way to configure Wordpress to use SMTP is through [a plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=smtp).

Comment: thanks for your answer, I downloaded a plugin and checked. it works fine!! that means SMTP works ok. but wordpress emailing are not sending. then where/which files I need to check?

Comment: You shouldn't need to check any files. Buddypress and Contact Form 7 are well known plugins with good ratings. They are probably working fine.  If you can send SMTP email from your test.php file then I would guess that either 1. The SMTP plugin is configured wrong, or 2. Contact Form 7 and Buddypress are configured wrong. You might also try contacting support at your web host.